# Changing char[]array letter and replacing it

Tags: java, string

I want to encrypt the String `"Klartext"` by just replacing each individual letter with the one 3 steps ahead in the alphabet.

I have this Code:

```
String Klartext = "test";
int x,Laenge = Klartext.length();
char[] Alphabet = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z'};
char[] array = Klartext.toCharArray();

for (x=0;x < Laenge ;x++ ) {
  System.out.println(x);

  char str = array[x];
  System.out.println(array[x]);
  int y = Arrays.asList(Alphabet).indexOf('b');

  System.out.print(y);
```

When I run it, I get

```
0 t -11 e -12 s -13 t -1
```

It should get me

```
0 t 19 1 e 5 2 s 18 3 t 19
```

So that I can change the letter `t` into `w` by simply replacing it with:

```
String a = array[y+3];
```

Comment: Look at the [API docs of class `String`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html). You'll find methods there that you can use for this.

Comment: So which part of the task you are no able to do? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
   char[] toCharacterArray ( String s )
   {
      return s.toCharArray();
   }
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it's quite simple to convert a string into indivitual letters.

A string is a chain of characters, so you only have to separate it, how?

You create an array where you will save all the characters, and you split the string into that array, just like this:

```
//This is your string.
String str;

//And in this array you will save the characters from the array.
String[] arr = str.split("");
```

Hope it helps you.